# Go - check Firestore document exists

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I can't seem to check if a document exists. If it doesn't exist it goes to an error rather than just an empty document

```
 "error": "rpc error: code = NotFound desc = \"projects/PROJECTID/databases/(default)/documents/claimed/123abc\" not found"
```

The code in question, values have be replaced with placeholders.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, "PROJECTID")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    docRef := client.Collection("claimed").Doc("123abc")
    doc, err := docRef.Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err // <----- Reverts to here
    }

    // Doesn't make it to here
    if doc.Exists() {
        return errors.New("document ID already exists")
    } else {
        _, err := docRef.Set(ctx, /* custom object here */)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
}
```

The code documentation for `Get()` says

```
// Get retrieves the document. If the document does not exist, Get return a NotFound error, which
// can be checked with
//    status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound
// In that case, Get returns a non-nil DocumentSnapshot whose Exists method return false and whose
// ReadTime is the time of the failed read operation.
```

So is my solution to just modify the error handling instead? `if err != nil { /* check it exists */ }

** Solution **

```golang
    docRef := client.Collection("claimed").Doc("123abc")
    doc, err := docRef.Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        if status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound {
            // Handle document not existing here
            _, err := docRef.Set(ctx, /* custom object here */)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        } else {
            return err
        }
    }
    
    // Double handling (???)
    if doc.Exists() {
        // Handle document existing here
    }
```

Comment: Looks like `Exists()` only works on documents which already exist which is counter intuitive to what you'd expect and how other SDKs for Firestore work. The requirement to first `Get()` an existing document to check if it exists doesn't make sense to me, but I have now got a working solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get an error if the document doesn't exist.

You use the fact that you get the error for non-existence.

See the documentation for [Get](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef.Get) for handling the error.

```golang
doc, err := docRef.Get(ctx)
  if err != nil {
    if status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: So where does `Exist()` come into play? Seems redundant if `Get()` throws an error?

Comment: Make sure you import "google.golang.org/grpc/codes" and "google.golang.org/grpc/status"