# Why can I not catch the does not exist error inside a transaction when updating in Firestore?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to catch a not-exists document error and provide a more specific error message on failure, but the update method never returns an error in the callback of the transaction. I have ensured that the user does not exist and there is no document. I do get an error that just says the document does not exist, but the error is returned after the transaction, not from the update call.

I can get this to work if I check the existence of the document first, but that's an extra read I wanted to avoid. I also don't need the document reference as I am just appending to the array, so I assumed update will fail if there is no document found.

```
    // Fetch document references
    userRef := s.firestore.Collection("users").Doc(params.UserID)
    dashboardRef := s.firestore.Collection("dashboards").Doc(params.DashboardID)

    // Begin Firestore transaction
    if err := s.firestore.RunTransaction(ctx, func(ctx context.Context, tx *firestore.Transaction) error {
        // User data to update
        userUpdates := []firestore.Update{
            {
                Path:  "sharedWithMeDashboardIDs",
                Value: firestore.ArrayUnion(params.DashboardID),
            },
        }

        fmt.Println("user update")
        // Attempt to update the user document
        if err := tx.Update(userRef, userUpdates); err != nil {

            // SHOULD BE AN ERROR HERE, BUT NEVER HITS THIS STATEMENT

            fmt.Println(err)
            // Check if the error is because the document doesn't exist
            if status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound {
                return fmt.Errorf("user %s does not exist", params.UserID)
            }
            return err
        }

                ...rest of code

        fmt.Println("called")
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Both logging statements outside of the error block are called. I do indeed return nil in the callback function, but no error is returned from update as I believe it should.

I do get a general error despite returning nil in the callback function:

```
rpc error: code = NotFound desc = No document to update: projects/{myproject}/databases/(default)/documents/users/invalid-user
```

I have set it to be a single retry as well (one call in total), and it still fails. There is some underlying logic (hard to dig into, they interface it) that is generating a does not exist error, but update never errors out or returns my error. I have a similar update in dashboards that I left out, but I want to follow the same logic.

My best guess is that it works (returns my error) when it's a reads a document, because reads are probably batched before writes, and writes are batched with retries meaning it may be calling the function multiple times, but I'd still expected my error to bubble up on the update failure instead of getting a generic error.

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef.Get), **Get** retrieves the document, if the document does not exist, it returns a NotFound error which is check with the `status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound`. Checkout this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69936219/go-check-firestore-document-exists#:~:text=If%20the%20document%20does%20not,of%20the%20failed%20read%20operation.)

Comment: I understand that, but Firestore charges by the query. Update should fail here and return an error because there is no document to update. Doing an additional get request here to me makes no sense. Update should fail with an error if there's no document. The code in update does not get called at all (no error is returned from update, even with non-existing doc).